# How to change page location in Wordpress

Tags: menus, permalinks, homepage, paginate-links

I want to change my page location (link address). My blog page location is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1336.
```

I want to change blog page location

`http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1336` to `http://localhost/wordpress/`

I want to create a option for user "Please select a page for home page". User selected page show as home page. For this reason I need to change page location. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "Settings" -> "Reading" in the wp-admin you (or other users) can set which page should be used as the home page.

Comment: I want to set this option on my theme option panel.